# Mercurial, authentication by key

Tags: mercurial, ssh

I have such section in my `~/.hgrc` config file

```
[auth]
repo.prefix = ssh://hguser@192.168.132.72/repos
repo.key = /home/zerkms/.ssh/mercurial-repo/id_rsa
```

But when I write:

```
hg clone ssh://hguser@192.168.132.72/repos/rps .
```

mercurial still requires password to enter.

What have I done wrong?

To prevent obvious questions:

Yes, there is a valid key in the specified path and it works if use it with `ssh-agent`.

My question is how to work with keys in `[auth]` section.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`auth` isn't for SSH](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#auth). The key needs to be loaded in another way. If it were just ~/.ssh/id_rsa it would be done automatically, as it's not you may need to do something to register it. Using ~/.ssh/id_rsa is the easiest way normally - put the contents of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the target machine and you're ready.

Comment: What if I need several keys? I cannot have several `~/.ssh/id_rsa` files :-S

Comment: I only use one key, for myself.

Comment: well, I'll work through ssh-agent then. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: zerkms: If you need several differnet keys, you can configure this with an IdentityFile setting in `~/.ssh/config` (see `man ssh_config`) or by `hg clone --ssh "ssh -i ~/.ssh/yourkey" ...`.

Comment: @MartinGeisler You should really make that an answer.

Answer (score 22):

The following works for me (probably a new setting since the question was asked):

Add to hgrc:

```
[ui]
ssh = ssh -C -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa-mercurialkey
```

-C to enable compression, -i to specify identity file. If the key is loaded into ssh-agent, I don't get asked again for passphrase.

Comment: Also, please note that the private key that is provided with -i flag should only be readable by the current user (permissions 600 would do) otherwise it will be ignored during ssh checkout.

Comment: Sometimes (like ssh for wIndows) it might be helpful to specify the username as well, so the line is `ssh = ssh -C -i C:\Users\username\.ssh\id_rsa -l username`